# Passing string around in C++

Tags: c++, string, reference

I would like to pass a string to different objects so that they can manipulate it. However, I can't get it to work. Here is what I have - based on the SO threads it's supposed to work with passing by reference?

```cpp
struct A {
  std::string aString = "";
};
struct B {
  std::string bString;

  B(std::string& str_) : bString(str_) {}
};
static void run() {
  A a;
  a.aString = "in A";
  B b(a.aString);
  b.bString += "...also in b";
  std::cout << "A: " << a.aString << std::endl;  // A: in A
  std::cout << "B: " << b.bString << std::endl;  // B: in A...also in b
}
```

I would like to have it so that all objects can write to this string (i.e. that both objects hold "B: in A...also in b").

I have found a workaround by wrapping the `string` in another object and passing that as `shared_ptr`. However, I was hoping there is a simpler solution.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `aString` and `bString` are independent objects. `std::shared_ptr` is the way to go.

Comment: The problem is that `std::string bString;` is not a reference.

Comment: Why do you need this? Why not just pass it by reference to the functions that needs it? It's _a lot_ easier to only have _one_ owner

Comment: @TedLyngmo : I'm building a JSON object out of a command structure to pass it to node. For the `node->C++` part, I use RapidJSON, but for `C++->node`, writing to a string directly is much faster.

Comment: @Markstar _"much faster"_ - than what? Than using RapidJSONs built-in support what also creates proper JSON objects? Even so, that's no reason to share ownership of the string.

Comment: @TedLyngmo : If you think so. Though I would say that is rather off topic. Interesting that SO is so fastidious about greetings and other niceties but this is okay. :/

Anyways, thank you for your time, I guess I'll wrap the string for now.

Comment: _"... but this is okay. :/"_ - I'm not sure what you're getting at. I asked you why you need this and you said something that (at least to me) doesn't explain why you need it. Also, using a `std::shared_ptr` to access the `std::string` and build the object manually will most probably not be faster than using RapidJSON to make the JSON object. Instead of assuming that RapidJSON won't be rapid enough, try it out and measure.

Comment: Constructing the string by hand is definitely faster. And if I understand "Jason Turner's" lessons about function optimizations correctly, then even the wrapper should come at a minimal/no overhead cost. But that's exactly why I was asking for a simpler solution without the extra code.

Comment: _"Construction the string by hand is definitely faster"_ - So, you **have** measured? How much faster was it? If you show the serializer you used and the way you manually built the JSON objects when you compared, it'll be easier to understand what you actually need. Since you didn't use a wrapper/`std::shared_ptr` when you did this comparison, why not present the code you _did_ use and tell us where you'd like to introduce the wrapper, and also, for what reason. I'm thinking this is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Again, thank you for taking time to respond. I'm of course not posting my code, that would be a colossal waste of time. All I wanted to know is if there is a way to pass a string around similarly to all the other variables and objects that we can pass. People are using C++ for all different use cases and there are a lot of complaints out there that C++ is too vast for its own good. I don't agree, but this is a good example how instead of having a simple answer, the go-to reply is to question OP's sanity. I'm out.

Comment: _"if there is a way to pass a string around similarly to all the other variables and objects"_ - Yes, you can pass a `std::string` around just like any other object. **How** to do it properly depends very much on what actually need it for. Letting different objects share the ownership of the `std::string` is very likely both confusing and inefficient. _"instead of having a simple answer"_ - It _could_ have been simple to answer if we'd gotten enough details. Again, it smells very much like an XY problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the member variable `bString` is its own instance of a  `string`, it is not a reference to a `string`. Even though `B`'s constructor takes in a reference, as soon as `bString` is initialized, it makes a copy of the string passed in.

To get the behavior you want, try this:

```
std::string& bString;
```

Comment: Ahh, thank you. I had actually tried that before posting but had introduced a typo along with it, so when that didn't work I thought it was because something else was going on. So yeah, it works!

Answer (score -1):

By passing the string as reference, any modification to the referred-to string should result in a modification -- to the original string. References are essentially constant pointers (*const) that are dereferenced each time they are used.